# Bizarre airflow behaviour with Variables/GCP Secrets

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have observed some very bizarre behaviour recently in Airflow (running in Google Cloud Composer):

I updated my DAG and it was deployed to the dags directory (a Google Storage bucket).

Airflow reported and error: one of the GCP Secrets I was trying to look up (with `Variable.get("varname")`) was not found:

> KeyError(f'Variable {key} does not exist')

I checked in the Secret Manager and the key was there, *with* the appropriate prefix ("airflow-variables-").

This seemed strange but I didn't have time to look into it. I came back a while later, refreshed the page, and this time, Airflow still only reported a single error, but it was complaining about a *different* variable - which *also* exists.

I decided to refresh every ~10 minutes and noticed that the variable that Airflow complains about sometimes changes each time I refresh the Airflow UI.

There was also one instance where Airflow did not report *any* errors and showed me my newly updated DAGs - I wish I had run them when I had the chance!

Has anyone ever heard of Airflow doing something like this? Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

(Airflow version is 2.2.3, running in Google Cloud Composer)

Comment: Why you specified the prefix? You can call the variable as you like in the secrets
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_images/aws-secrets-manager.png

Comment: Oh sorry, you meant environment variables. I have the same version but never happened to something like that. Variable.get("foo") still works for me

Comment: @MarcoMassetti For our Airflow environment, we set up the variables with a prefix in GCP Secret Manager and then we access them _without_ the prefix in the DAG. This works for other DAGs accessing these same variables, so I'm not sure why this DAG is having a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging around in the logs, I saw some timeout messages related to retrieving secrets. A little more research based on this suggested that too many calls to `Variable.get` could significantly slow things down. Looking at my code, I realized that my files had a number of redundant calls to retrieve variables.

I refactored in such a way that most Airflow Variables only get retrieved once and their values get passed in to the code that needs them. The problem seems to be resolved.